# Coroutines or Php script not working on mobile

Tags: c#, php, android, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Hi this is my first query using stack overflow so lets get to it. i am making an android game that uses database that is on a server of a site i am using phpmyadmin to manage mysql and 
here is how i retrieve data

```
public class Dataretrieve : MonoBehaviour {
WWW sitedata;
public string[] users;
public static string[] Usernames;
public static string[] Emails;
public static string[] Passwords;
public static string[] Icons;
// Use this for initialization
public  void Start(){
    StartCoroutine_Auto(StartGettingData);
}

public IEnumerator StartGettingData () {
    Debug.Log ("Starting to get values");
    sitedata = new WWW ("mysite/database.php");
    yield return sitedata;

    string sitedatatext = sitedata.text;
    users = sitedatatext.Split (';');

    Usernames=new string[users.Length-1];
    Emails=new string[users.Length-1];
    Passwords=new string[users.Length-1];
    Icons=new string[users.Length-1];

    for (int i=0; i<users.Length-1; i++) 
    {
        Usernames[i]=GetData(users[i],"Username:");
        Emails[i]=GetData(users[i],"Email:");
        Passwords[i]=GetData(users[i],"Password:");
        Icons[i]=GetData(users[i],"Icon:");
    }
    Debug.Log ("All Data Retrieved");
    StopCoroutine ("StartGettingData");
}
    string GetData(string data,string index)
{
    string value = data.Substring (data.IndexOf (index) + index.Length);
    if (value.Contains ("|"))
        value = value.Remove (value.IndexOf ("|"));
    return value;
}

public void values()
{
    Debug.Log ("Start getting values again");
    StartCoroutine_Auto(StartGettingData());
    StopCoroutine ("StartGettingData");
    Debug.Log ("Values Updated again");
}
```

}

The problem is it works fine on unity editor but when i run it on built it doesn't get users data

here's php code

```css
$conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbName);
if(!$conn)
{
 die("Connection Failled".mysqli_connect_error() );
}

$sql="SELECT ID, Email, Password, Username, Icon FROM  Login_Variables";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 while( $row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  echo("ID:".$row['ID']."|Email:".$row['Email']."|Password:".$row['Password']."|Username:".$row['Username']."|Icon:".$row['Icon'].";");
 }
```

Comment: Where is the php file hosted? Local or on the internet?

Comment: over the internet but using local host

Comment: hey Ahmad, your code has drastic problems. You should not be calling "StopCoroutine" inside the same coroutine.  (simply "yield break" if you happen to want to leave, exit, a coroutine.)

Comment: dude WTF is "StartCoroutine_Auto" ?  Heh.  delete that immediately - you just want "StartCoroutine".  you ALSO must delete the other "StopCoroutine" in "values".  be sure to delete ALL uses of "StopCoroutine" seen above.  note that "values" MUST be called "Values".  you MUST use the correct case pattern for classnames, variable names in Unity3D.

Comment: thank you guys that helped a lot but i found out that was not the source of the problem